# Помогите разобраться Failed to resolve dependency '@babel/runtime@7.20.13

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Я хочу протестировать приложения написанное на react-native мне нужно подключить зависимость "@babel/runtime": "^7.22.15" она не вызывает ошибок если проверять через приложения expo go , но я хочу проверить его через snack.expo.dev и тут мне пишет Failed to resolve dependency '@babel/runtime@7.20.13' (Can't resolve '' in '/tmp/snackager/snackager/buildStatus/1/@babel~runtime@7.20.13-ios,android,web/package'

мне нужно подбирать другие версии пока не подойдет ?
Другого способа нет ?

Answer (score 0):

может пригодится кому то, нужно понизить версию axios до 0.27.2 @babel/runtime, встроенной в Expo.